Quarkus framework REST api Two DB methods parallel execution
Quarkus Rest API end point implementation, Need some guidance on implementing solution.
---PersonController.java--
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/api/v1")
Class PersonController {
@Inject
PersonService personService;
@GET
@Path("/persons")
public List <Persons> getPersons(){
personService.getAllPersons();
}
}

--PersonRepository--
Class PersonSeriveImpl {
@Inject
PersonService personService;

public List <Persons> getPersons(){
   List<Citizens> citizensList = personService.getCitizens(); //Step1
   List<NoncitizensList> noncitizensList = personService.getNonCitizens(); //Step2

// Business logic on List<Citizens> & List<Noncitizens>
List<Persons> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personlist.addAll(citizensList);
personlist.addAll(noncitizensList);
return personList;
}
}

For example Say if Step1 is taking 5 mins and Step2 taking 5 mins then I want to execute Step1 & Step2 in Parallel execution so it will less than 10 mins say around 5mins.
can somebody suggest how to implement parallel execution in Quarkus framework.
I have tried ExecutorService and threadpool Executor but end having some issues.

Hi. There is nothing really Quarkus specific about this, the answer would be pretty much the same in plain Java :)
